# How to pass String from One Activity to another Activity and use it in intent for Dialpad and Email

Tags: java, android

I have two one Adapter and another Activity . Adapter send the String Extra as per position in Firebase Data Structure into Next activity where data is displayed which is passed from Adapter. 
It works pretty well. I am ablet to show the data in Textview. But When I user intent to Dial a phone or send Email , Then I'm not able to use Extras I"m receivng with but when I setText in Textview ..they show the exact Data. Please help

Here is the method in Adapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        dbreference = database.getReference("gender");

        g = bookslist.get(position);
 holder.teacher_quali.setText(g.getBqualifications());

        holder.profile_details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), gender_details.class);

                intent.putExtra(NEAR_LOCATION, g.getBlocation());
                intent.putExtra(AVAILAIBILITY, g.getBavailaile());

                intent.putExtra(MOBILE, g.getSellermobile());
                intent.putExtra(EMAIL, g.getSelleremail());


                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
});
```

where I have defined MOBILE and EMAIL as

```
public static final String MOBILE = "other_mobile";
public static final String EMAIL= "other_email";
```

in same adapter view and my activity is

```
public class gender_details extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView tutor_email,tutor_mobile;
    private ImageView img;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.profile_details);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_details); // get the reference of Toolbar
        toolbar.setTitle(getIntent().getStringExtra(KEY_NAME));
        toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_person_black_24dp);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);




        String tutor_email_txt = "";
        String tutor_mobile_txt = "";


        tutor_email_txt = intent.getStringExtra(EMAIL);
        tutor_mobile_txt = intent.getStringExtra(MOBILE);
        // Setting values

        TextView Email_Txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tutor_email);
        Email_Txt.setText(tutor_email_txt);

         TextView Contact_Txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tutor_contact);
        Contact_Txt.setText(String tutor_mobile_txt);
    }
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }
// Activity's overrided method used to perform click events on menu items
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
//noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
// Display menu item's title by using a Toast.
            if (id == R.id.action_call) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+tutor_mobile_txt));
                startActivity(intent);


                return true;
            } else if (id == R.id.action_email) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("plain/text");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, tutor_email_txt);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "mail body");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""));

                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(gender_details.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

As you can see in Textview , information are shown correctl but when I use to Intent Action Dail or send email...I'm not been able to do so.

Please help

Comment: whats the problem..Dailer and email intent is opening but the data is not showing ?

Comment: Problem is when I use  tutor_email_txt, it is highlighed in red color and show error.

Comment: See My Answer..

Comment: Access email and phone number directly from getIntent().getStringExtra(EMAIL) and getIntent().getStringExtra(MOBILE)
Or you can access email phone number from textview getText like Contact_Txt.getText().toString().
You don't need to take any extra variable for it.

Comment: Free Advice : Please follow java naming convention for better readability.

Comment: @Sanoop Thanks..now since it has been resolved...I now my error point..I was not using these two variables inside onCreate but instead in menu..so I had to declare them as public. Thanks it has been solved now and yes I will remember that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this:**

Declare the variable Globally

```html
public class gender_details extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView tutor_email,tutor_mobile;
    private ImageView img;
     String tutor_email_txt;
        String tutor_mobile_txt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.profile_details);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_details); // get the reference of Toolbar
        toolbar.setTitle(getIntent().getStringExtra(KEY_NAME));
        toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_person_black_24dp);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);




       


        tutor_email_txt = intent.getStringExtra(EMAIL);
        tutor_mobilee_txt = intent.getStringExtra(MOBILE);
        // Setting values

        TextView Email_Txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tutor_email);
        Email_Txt.setText(tutor_email_txt);

         TextView Contact_Txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tutor_contact);
        Contact_Txt.setText(String tutor_mobile_txt);
    }
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }
// Activity's overrided method used to perform click events on menu items
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
//noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
// Display menu item's title by using a Toast.
            if (id == R.id.action_call) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+tutor_mobile_txt));
                startActivity(intent);


                return true;
            } else if (id == R.id.action_email) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("plain/text");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, tutor_email_txt);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "mail body");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""));

                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(gender_details.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Are You Declare Permission in Manifest If Not Then Declare it :**

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"

Answer (score 0):

There are some serious naming problems in your code. First you need to make your tutor_mobile_txt variable global. Secondly inside onCreate your are initializing tutor_mobilee_txt instead of tutor_mobile_txt. Correct the spellings and then check.

Comment: Sorry that was typing error ..I've corrected my question. How to make variable global?

Comment: String tutor_mobile_txt = ""; at the top where you have declared textview variables